Tex4ebook section numbers in index don't work anymore
I have successfully used the recipe described in
tex4ht: indexentries/structure of the .ind-file
to get nicely formatted links with the format e.g. 12.3.1 in the index of my eBook with the TeX installation that comes with Ubuntu 20.04. After upgrading to 24.04, it did not work anymore and I followed the hint of michal.h21 given in
Indexing with tex4ebook showing undefined control sequence
that indexing is now supported out of the box by htlatex and removed indexing4ht from the config and copies imakeindex.4ht into the correct location in the TeX installation. Now indexing works, but it just shows consecutive numbering of sections like 3443, which is not very intuitive for the reader. Is there a simple way to get it working again? If I understand corretly, the command getCurrentSectionNumber
\newcommand\getCurrentSectionNumber{%
  \ifnum\c@section=0 %
  \thechapter
  \else
  \ifnum\c@subsection=0 %
  \thesection
  \else
  \ifnum\c@subsubsection=0 %
  \thesubsection
  \else
  \thesubsubsection
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
}

was responsible for the format I would like to have.

The problem with using section numbers for index is that backlinks from the index will point back to sections, not to the place where the index entry was saved. This may work only if you use a lot of subsections.
It is not that hard to adapt the current indexing code to use section numbers. Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex 
\makeindex[name=foo,title=Test] 
 
\begin{document} 
\section{First}
Test1\index{Test1} 
Test2\index[foo]{Test2} 

\section{second}
Test3\index{Test3} 
Test4\index[foo]{Test4}. 
\subsection{Subsection}
And Test1\index{Test1} again. 
 
\printindex 
\printindex[foo] 
\end{document}

It uses the imakeidx package. We then can change the configuration file imakeidx.4ht to save links to sections:
% imakeidx.4ht (2024-05-22-14:13), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2019-2024 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2024-05-22-14:13}

\def\idx:getCurrentSectionNumber{%
  \ifnum\c@section=0 %
  \thechapter
  \else
  \ifnum\c@subsection=0 %
  \thesection
  \else
  \ifnum\c@subsubsection=0 %
  \thesubsection
  \else
  \thesubsubsection
  \fi
  \fi
  \fi
}



\def\:temp#1#2#3{
\expandafter\protected@write\csname#1@idxfile\endcsname{}%
{\string\beforeentry{\RefFileNumber\FileNumber}{\CurSecHaddr}{\a:makeindex}}%
\o:imki@wrindexentrysplit:{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\HLet\imki@wrindexentrysplit\:temp

\ifx \a:makeindex\:UnDef
\NewConfigure{makeindex}{1}
\fi

\Configure{makeindex}{\idx:getCurrentSectionNumber}
\Configure{@begin}{theindex}{\ind:defs\imki@maybeaddtotoc\imki@idxprologue\global\let\imki@idxprologue\relax}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand\:saveindex[2][]{\seq_gput_right:Nn\:savedindex{[#1]{#2}}}
\def\:printsavedindex{\seq_map_inline:Nn\:savedindex{\index##1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\Hinput{imakeidx}
\endinput

We also need to update make4ht indexing library, make4ht-indexing.lua to support section numbers:

local M = {}
local log = logging.new "indexing"

-- Handle accented characters in files created with \usepackage[utf]{inputenc}
-- this code was originally part of https://github.com/michal-h21/iec2utf/
local enc = {}

local licrs = {}
local codepoint2utf = unicode.utf8.char 
local used_encodings = {}

-- load inputenc encoding file
local function load_encfiles(f)
    local file= io.open(f,"r")
    local encodings = file:read("*all")
    file:close()
    for codepoint, licr in encodings:gmatch('DeclareUnicodeCharacter(%b{})(%b{})') do
        local codepoint = codepoint2utf(tonumber(codepoint:sub(2,-2),16))
        local licr= licr:sub(2,-2):gsub('@tabacckludge','')
        licrs[licr] = codepoint
    end
end

local function sanitize_licr(l)
    return l:gsub(" (.)",function(s) if s:match("[%a]") then return " "..s else return s end end):sub(2,-2)
end

local load_enc = function(enc)
  -- use default encodings if used doesn't provide one
  enc = enc or  {"T1","T2A","T2B","T2C","T3","T5", "LGR"}
    for _,e in pairs(enc) do
        local filename = e:lower() .. "enc.dfu"
    -- don't process an enc file multiple times
    if not used_encodings[filename] then
      local dfufile = kpse.find_file(filename)
      if dfufile then
        load_encfiles(dfufile)
      end
    end
    used_encodings[filename] = true
    end
end



local cache = {}

local get_utf8 = function(input)
    local output = input:gsub('\\IeC[%s]*(%b{})',function(iec)
    -- remove \protect commands 
    local iec = iec:gsub("\\protect%s*", "")
        local code = cache[iec] or licrs[sanitize_licr(iec)] or '\\IeC '..iec
        -- print(iec, code)
        cache[iec] = code
        return code
    end)
    return output
end


-- parse the idx file produced by tex4ht
-- it replaces the document page numbers by index entry number
-- each index entry can then link to place in the HTML file where the
-- \index command had been used

local parse_idx = function(content)
  -- index entry number
  local current_entry = 0
  -- map between index entry number and corresponding HTML file and destination
  local map = {}
  local buffer = {}

  for line in content:gmatch("([^\n]+)") do
    if line:match("^\\beforeentry") then
      -- increment index entry number
      current_entry = current_entry + 1
      local file, dest, locator = line:match("\\beforeentry%s*{(.-)}{(.-)}{(.-)}")
      locator = locator == "" and nil or locator
      map[current_entry] = {file = file, dest = dest, locator = locator}
    elseif line:match("^\\indexentry") then
      -- replace the page number with the current
      -- index entry number
      local result = line:gsub("%b{}$", "{"..current_entry .."}")
      buffer[#buffer+1] = get_utf8(result)
    else
      buffer[#buffer+1] = line
    end
  end
  -- return table with page to dest map and updated idx file
  return {map = map, idx = table.concat(buffer, "\n")}
end


-- replace numbers in .ind file with links back to text
local function replace_index_pages(rest, entries)
 return rest:gsub("%{?(%d+)%}?", function(page)
   local entry = entries[tonumber(page)]
   if entry then
     page = entry.locator or page
     -- construct link to the index entry
     return "\\Link[" .. entry.file .."]{".. entry.dest .."}{}" .. page .."\\EndLink{}"
   else
     return page
   end
 end)
end


-- replace page numbers in the ind file with hyperlinks
local fix_idx_pages = function(content, idxobj)
  local buffer = {}
  local entries = idxobj.map
  for  line in content:gmatch("([^\n]+)")  do
    local line, count = line:gsub("(%s*\\%a+.-%,)(.+)$", function(start,rest)
      -- there is a problem when index term itself contains numbers, like Bible verses (1:2),
      -- because they will be detected as page numbers too. I cannot find a good solution 
      -- that wouldn't break something else.
      -- There can be also commands with numbers in braces. These numbers in braces will be ignored, 
      -- as they may be not page numbers
      return start .. replace_index_pages(rest, entries)    end)
    -- longer index entries may be broken over several lines, in that case, we need to process only numbers
    if count == 0 then
      line = line:gsub("(%s*%d+.+)", function(rest)
        return replace_index_pages(rest, entries)
      end)
    end
    buffer[#buffer+1] = line
  end
  return table.concat(buffer, "\n")
end

-- prepare the .idx file produced by tex4ht
-- for use with Xindy or Makeindex
local prepare_idx = function(filename)
  local f = io.open(filename, "r")
  if not f then return nil, "Cannot open file :".. tostring(filename) end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  local idx = parse_idx(content)
  local idxname = os.tmpname()
  local f = io.open(idxname, "w")
  f:write(idx.idx)
  f:close()
  -- return the object with mapping between dummy page numbers 
  -- and link destinations in the files, and the temporary .idx file
  -- these can be used for the processing with the index processor
  return idx, idxname
end

-- add links to a index file
local process_index = function(indname, idx)
  local f = io.open(indname,  "r")
  if not f then return  nil, "Cannot open .ind file: " .. tostring(indname) end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()

  local newcontent = fix_idx_pages(content, idx)
  local f = io.open(indname,"w")
  f:write(newcontent)
  f:close()
  return true
end

local get_idxname = function(par)
  return par.idxfile or par.input .. ".idx"
end

local prepare_tmp_idx = function(par)
  par.idxfile = mkutils.file_in_builddir(get_idxname(par), par)
  if not par.idxfile or not mkutils.file_exists(par.idxfile) then return nil, "Cannot load idx file " .. (par.idxfile or "''") end
  -- construct the .ind name, based on the .idx name
  par.indfile = par.indfile or par.idxfile:gsub("idx$", "ind")
  load_enc()
  -- save hyperlinks and clean the .idx file
  local idxdata, newidxfile = prepare_idx(par.idxfile)
  if not idxdata then
    -- if the prepare_idx function returns nil, the second reuturned value contains error msg
    return nil, newidxfile
  end
  return  newidxfile, idxdata
end


local splitindex = function(par)
  local files = {}
  local idxfiles = {}
  local buffer 
  local idxfile = get_idxname(par)
  if not idxfile or not mkutils.file_exists(idxfile) then return nil, "Cannot load idx file " .. (idxfile or "''") end
  for line in io.lines(idxfile) do
    local file = line:match("indexentry%[(.-)%]")
    if file then
      -- generate idx name for the current output file
      file =  par.input .. "-" ..file .. ".idx"
      local current = files[file] or {}
      -- remove file name from the index entry
      local indexentry = line:gsub("indexentry%[.-%]", "indexentry")
      -- save the index entry and preseding line to the current buffer
      table.insert(current, buffer)
      table.insert(current, indexentry)
      files[file] = current
    end
    -- 
    buffer = line
  end
  -- save idx files
  for filename, contents in pairs(files) do
    log:info("Saving split index file: " .. filename)
    idxfiles[#idxfiles+1] = filename
    local f = io.open(filename, "w")
    f:write(table.concat(contents, "\n"))
    f:close()
  end
  return idxfiles
end

local function run_indexing_command (command, par)
  -- detect command name from the command. It will be the first word
  local cmd_name = command:match("^[%a]+") or "indexing"
  local xindylog  = logging.new(cmd_name)
  -- support split index
  local subindexes = splitindex(par) or {}
  if #subindexes > 0 then
    -- call the command again on all files produced by splitindex
    for _, subindex in ipairs(subindexes) do
      -- make copy of the parameters
      local t = {}
      for k,v in pairs(par) do t[k] = v end
      t.idxfile = subindex
      run_indexing_command(command, t)
    end
    return nil
  end
  local newidxfile, idxdata = prepare_tmp_idx(par)
  if not newidxfile then
    -- the idxdata will contain error message in the case of error
    xindylog:warning(idxdata)
    return false
  end
  par.newidxfile = newidxfile
  xindylog:debug("Prepared temporary idx file: ", newidxfile)
  -- prepare modules
  local xindy_call = command % par
  xindylog:info(xindy_call)
  local status = mkutils.execute(xindy_call)
  -- insert correct links to the index
  local status, msg = process_index(par.indfile, idxdata)
  if not status then xindylog:warning(msg) end
  -- remove the temporary idx file
  os.remove(newidxfile)
  -- null the indfile, it is necessary in order to support
  -- multiple indices
  par.indfile = nil
end


M.get_utf8 = get_utf8
M.load_enc = load_enc
M.parse_idx = parse_idx
M.fix_idx_pages = fix_idx_pages
M.prepare_idx = prepare_idx
M.process_index = process_index
M.prepare_tmp_idx = prepare_tmp_idx
M.run_indexing_command = run_indexing_command
return M

You can use a following build file:
Make:htlatex {}
Make:makeindex {}
Make:makeindex {idxfile = "foo.idx"}
-- Make:xindex {}
Make:htlatex {}

This is the result:


Thank your very much, @michal.h21!
I have installed the latest version of make4ht and I can reproduce the MWE.
Now I want to do the same with my eBook project, but I only get 0s in the index, like this:
data flow, 0

I try to dig deeper into this.

@BernhardScheffold can you post a MWE that shows this issue?

I just compiled your MWE with tex4ebook and it works out nicely. Either I find the issue with my eBook or I distill an MWE from it.

@BernhardScheffold it could be caused by your document class or used packages, so MWE is most likely needed.

I tried to do an MWE with exactly the same stuff before the \begin{document}. The MWE behaves nicely, so I have to try further. The book pulls in all the chapters with \input, so I also tried to put the sample stuff in a second file. But it still behaves! I got to try further.

@BernhardScheffold OK, so this may be cause by some command you use in your document?

I finally managed to get it working. You were right about the commands. The main culprit was a \index inside a \caption inside a \begin{figure}. So I pulled this out of the \caption. Minor troubles include duplicated (I think I can deal that by reducing the \index hints if there is no way to easily filter them out) and a seealso like this
\index{ERP|seealso{enterprise resource planning system}}
This broke the index just before this term.

@BernhardScheffold these sounds like issues that should be possible to fix. Can you make a MWE that shows them?

sorry that it took so long. I had a travel around the globe. But now I can provide an MWE in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/733086/tex4ebook-index-duplicate-section-number-and-breaking-index-on-seealso-with-sect

@BernhardScheffold no worry, I will take a look, but probably tomorrow.
