Tex4ebook index duplicate section number and breaking index on seealso with section numbers
Referring to Tex4ebook section numbers in index don't work anymore
I created an MWE showing problems with the index generation:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc=true,columns=1,noautomatic]

\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
We talk about enterprise resource planning\index{enterprise resource planning|seealso{ERP}} systems.

\section{First Section}
  
\subsection{First Subsection}
Let's talk about buzz.\index{buzz}
Let's talk about buzz.\index{buzz}
Let's talk about buzz.\index{buzz}
Let's talk about boom.\index{boom}
Let's talk about buzz.\index{buzz}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

Now we talk about ERP\index{ERP}

\subsection{Second Subsection}

Let's talk about buzz.\index{buzz}

\backmatter

\printindex

\end{document}

I get an index that looks like this

I would think that there is only one 1.1.1 entry for buzz (like for boom). Also, I would expect that "enterprise resource planning" and "ERP" would appear in the index (which they do, when you remove the seealso). This might be connected with this warning:
[WARNING] domfilter: XML DOM parsing of sampleli1.html failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: .../texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/a) [char=1343]

[WARNING] domfilter: HTML DOM parsing failed as well


This is another bug in the make4ht indexing library. It adds links to all page numbers it finds in the index entries, but it removes surrounding braces. This creates issue for the \seealso command, which expects two arguments, but instead of the page number, it gets the \Link command:
  \item enterprise resource planning, \seealso{ERP}\Link[samplech1.html]{dx2-1001}{}1\EndLink{}

This results in the rest of \Link arguments ending in the generated HTML:
<span class="index-item">enterprise resource planning, <span 
class="cmti-10x-x-109">see also </span>ERP[samplech1.html]dx2-10011</a> 

The spurious </a> element causes DOM parsing error, because there is no starting <a> tag.
This version of make4ht-indexing.lua should fix it:

local M = {}
local log = logging.new "indexing"

-- Handle accented characters in files created with \usepackage[utf]{inputenc}
-- this code was originally part of https://github.com/michal-h21/iec2utf/
local enc = {}

local licrs = {}
local codepoint2utf = unicode.utf8.char 
local used_encodings = {}

-- load inputenc encoding file
local function load_encfiles(f)
    local file= io.open(f,"r")
    local encodings = file:read("*all")
    file:close()
    for codepoint, licr in encodings:gmatch('DeclareUnicodeCharacter(%b{})(%b{})') do
        local codepoint = codepoint2utf(tonumber(codepoint:sub(2,-2),16))
        local licr= licr:sub(2,-2):gsub('@tabacckludge','')
        licrs[licr] = codepoint
    end
end

local function sanitize_licr(l)
    return l:gsub(" (.)",function(s) if s:match("[%a]") then return " "..s else return s end end):sub(2,-2)
end

local load_enc = function(enc)
  -- use default encodings if used doesn't provide one
  enc = enc or  {"T1","T2A","T2B","T2C","T3","T5", "LGR"}
    for _,e in pairs(enc) do
        local filename = e:lower() .. "enc.dfu"
    -- don't process an enc file multiple times
    if not used_encodings[filename] then
      local dfufile = kpse.find_file(filename)
      if dfufile then
        load_encfiles(dfufile)
      end
    end
    used_encodings[filename] = true
    end
end



local cache = {}

local get_utf8 = function(input)
    local output = input:gsub('\\IeC[%s]*(%b{})',function(iec)
    -- remove \protect commands 
    local iec = iec:gsub("\\protect%s*", "")
        local code = cache[iec] or licrs[sanitize_licr(iec)] or '\\IeC '..iec
        -- print(iec, code)
        cache[iec] = code
        return code
    end)
    return output
end


-- parse the idx file produced by tex4ht
-- it replaces the document page numbers by index entry number
-- each index entry can then link to place in the HTML file where the
-- \index command had been used

local parse_idx = function(content)
  -- index entry number
  local current_entry = 0
  -- map between index entry number and corresponding HTML file and destination
  local map = {}
  local buffer = {}

  for line in content:gmatch("([^\n]+)") do
    if line:match("^\\beforeentry") then
      -- increment index entry number
      current_entry = current_entry + 1
      local file, dest, locator = line:match("\\beforeentry%s*{(.-)}{(.-)}{(.-)}")
      -- if the third argument to \beforeentry is not empty, 
      -- use it as a index entry locator instead of the index counter
      if locator and locator == "" then locator = nil end
      map[current_entry] = {file = file, dest = dest, locator = locator}
    elseif line:match("^\\indexentry") then
      -- replace the page number with the current
      -- index entry number
      local result = line:gsub("%b{}$", "{"..current_entry .."}")
      buffer[#buffer+1] = get_utf8(result)
    else
      buffer[#buffer+1] = line
    end
  end
  -- return table with page to dest map and updated idx file
  return {map = map, idx = table.concat(buffer, "\n")}
end


-- replace numbers in .ind file with links back to text
local function replace_index_pages(rest, entries)
  -- keep track of the previous page number
  local previous
  return rest:gsub("(%s*%-*%s*)(,?%s*)(%{?)(%d+)(%}?)", function(dash, coma, lbrace, page, rbrace)
    local entry = entries[tonumber(page)]
    if entry then
      page = entry.locator or page
      -- if the page number is the same as the previous one, don't create a link
      -- this can happen when we use section numbers as locators. for example, 
      -- we could get 1.1 -- 1.1, 1.1, so we want to keep only the first one
      if page == previous then
        previous = page
        return ""
      else
        previous = page
        -- construct link to the index entry
        return dash .. coma.. lbrace ..  "\\Link[" .. entry.file .."]{".. entry.dest .."}{}" ..  page .."\\EndLink{}" .. rbrace
      end
    else
      return dash .. coma .. lbrace .. page .. rbrace
    end
 end)
end


-- replace page numbers in the ind file with hyperlinks
local fix_idx_pages = function(content, idxobj)
  local buffer = {}
  local entries = idxobj.map
  for  line in content:gmatch("([^\n]+)")  do
    local line, count = line:gsub("(%s*\\%a+.-%,)(.+)$", function(start,rest)
      -- there is a problem when index term itself contains numbers, like Bible verses (1:2),
      -- because they will be detected as page numbers too. I cannot find a good solution 
      -- that wouldn't break something else.
      -- There can be also commands with numbers in braces. These numbers in braces will be ignored, 
      -- as they may be not page numbers
      return start .. replace_index_pages(rest, entries)    end)
    -- longer index entries may be broken over several lines, in that case, we need to process only numbers
    if count == 0 then
      line = line:gsub("(%s*%d+.+)", function(rest)
        return replace_index_pages(rest, entries)
      end)
    end
    buffer[#buffer+1] = line
  end
  return table.concat(buffer, "\n")
end

-- prepare the .idx file produced by tex4ht
-- for use with Xindy or Makeindex
local prepare_idx = function(filename)
  local f = io.open(filename, "r")
  if not f then return nil, "Cannot open file :".. tostring(filename) end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  local idx = parse_idx(content)
  local idxname = os.tmpname()
  local f = io.open(idxname, "w")
  f:write(idx.idx)
  f:close()
  -- return the object with mapping between dummy page numbers 
  -- and link destinations in the files, and the temporary .idx file
  -- these can be used for the processing with the index processor
  return idx, idxname
end

-- add links to a index file
local process_index = function(indname, idx)
  local f = io.open(indname,  "r")
  if not f then return  nil, "Cannot open .ind file: " .. tostring(indname) end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()

  local newcontent = fix_idx_pages(content, idx)
  local f = io.open(indname,"w")
  f:write(newcontent)
  f:close()
  return true
end

local get_idxname = function(par)
  return par.idxfile or par.input .. ".idx"
end

local prepare_tmp_idx = function(par)
  par.idxfile = mkutils.file_in_builddir(get_idxname(par), par)
  if not par.idxfile or not mkutils.file_exists(par.idxfile) then return nil, "Cannot load idx file " .. (par.idxfile or "''") end
  -- construct the .ind name, based on the .idx name
  par.indfile = par.indfile or par.idxfile:gsub("idx$", "ind")
  load_enc()
  -- save hyperlinks and clean the .idx file
  local idxdata, newidxfile = prepare_idx(par.idxfile)
  if not idxdata then
    -- if the prepare_idx function returns nil, the second reuturned value contains error msg
    return nil, newidxfile
  end
  return  newidxfile, idxdata
end


local splitindex = function(par)
  local files = {}
  local idxfiles = {}
  local buffer 
  local idxfile = get_idxname(par)
  if not idxfile or not mkutils.file_exists(idxfile) then return nil, "Cannot load idx file " .. (idxfile or "''") end
  for line in io.lines(idxfile) do
    local file = line:match("indexentry%[(.-)%]")
    if file then
      -- generate idx name for the current output file
      file =  par.input .. "-" ..file .. ".idx"
      local current = files[file] or {}
      -- remove file name from the index entry
      local indexentry = line:gsub("indexentry%[.-%]", "indexentry")
      -- save the index entry and preseding line to the current buffer
      table.insert(current, buffer)
      table.insert(current, indexentry)
      files[file] = current
    end
    -- 
    buffer = line
  end
  -- save idx files
  for filename, contents in pairs(files) do
    log:info("Saving split index file: " .. filename)
    idxfiles[#idxfiles+1] = filename
    local f = io.open(filename, "w")
    f:write(table.concat(contents, "\n"))
    f:close()
  end
  return idxfiles
end

local function run_indexing_command (command, par)
  -- detect command name from the command. It will be the first word
  local cmd_name = command:match("^[%a]+") or "indexing"
  local xindylog  = logging.new(cmd_name)
  -- support split index
  local subindexes = splitindex(par) or {}
  if #subindexes > 0 then
    -- call the command again on all files produced by splitindex
    for _, subindex in ipairs(subindexes) do
      -- make copy of the parameters
      local t = {}
      for k,v in pairs(par) do t[k] = v end
      t.idxfile = subindex
      run_indexing_command(command, t)
    end
    return nil
  end
  local newidxfile, idxdata = prepare_tmp_idx(par)
  if not newidxfile then
    -- the idxdata will contain error message in the case of error
    xindylog:warning(idxdata)
    return false
  end
  par.newidxfile = newidxfile
  xindylog:debug("Prepared temporary idx file: ", newidxfile)
  -- prepare modules
  local xindy_call = command % par
  xindylog:info(xindy_call)
  local status = mkutils.execute(xindy_call)
  -- insert correct links to the index
  local status, msg = process_index(par.indfile, idxdata)
  if not status then xindylog:warning(msg) end
  -- remove the temporary idx file
  os.remove(newidxfile)
  -- null the indfile, it is necessary in order to support
  -- multiple indices
  par.indfile = nil
end


M.get_utf8 = get_utf8
M.load_enc = load_enc
M.parse_idx = parse_idx
M.fix_idx_pages = fix_idx_pages
M.prepare_idx = prepare_idx
M.process_index = process_index
M.prepare_tmp_idx = prepare_tmp_idx
M.run_indexing_command = run_indexing_command
return M

In particular,  the function that adds links to page numbers now adds brackets that were originally used:
-- replace numbers in .ind file with links back to text
local function replace_index_pages(rest, entries)
  -- keep track of the previous page number
  local previous
  return rest:gsub("(%s*%-*%s*)(,?%s*)(%{?)(%d+)(%}?)", function(dash, coma, lbrace, page, rbrace)
    local entry = entries[tonumber(page)]
    if entry then
      page = entry.locator or page
      -- if the page number is the same as the previous one, don't create a link
      -- this can happen when we use section numbers as locators. for example, 
      -- we could get 1.1 -- 1.1, 1.1, so we want to keep only the first one
      if page == previous then
        previous = page
        return ""
      else
        previous = page
        -- construct link to the index entry
        return dash .. coma.. lbrace ..  "\\Link[" .. entry.file .."]{".. entry.dest .."}{}" ..  page .."\\EndLink{}" .. rbrace
      end
    else
      return dash .. coma .. lbrace .. page .. rbrace
    end
 end)
end

This is the result:


Hi @michal.h21, once more: thank you so much!
Sadly, I can not get this to work. I pulled the make4ht repo and did a fresh make and make install BIN_DIR=/usr/bin (for Ubuntu), but it stills spits out those warnings:
[WARNING] domfilter: .../texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/a) [char=1343]
The new make4ht-indexing.lua doesn' even seem to be called.

@BernhardScheffold do you use the build file with Make:makeindex{}? It needs to be called at least once, to create the correct .ind file.

I use this for building:
  Make:htlatex {}   Make:makeindex {}   Make:htlatex {}   Make:htlatex {}

strace to the rescue! Using strace, I found that actually an installation of make4ht in my home directory was used. I accidentally installed it there one time. After removing this, the warning was gone and seealso now works. So now I still have this issue with the duplicate section numbers as seen in my screenshot.

@BernhardScheffold it should work now

I pulled your latest version of make4ht, built and installed it. Made the same mistakes again when installing, but sudo make install BIN_DIR=/usr/bin/ TEXMFHOME=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ did it for my Ubuntu system.
The index looks good now for the MWE and also for the full book. I probably will have new questions regarding e.g. list of figures appearing in the front when I try to place them in the backmatter, but that will be a new topic.

@BernhardScheffold that's good to hear that it works now.

well, in the MWE everything is fine. In the complete book it is almost good. There still are a few occasional duplicates, but I could not yet produce an MWE for this.

@BernhardScheffold it is possible that there are some other delimiters between index numbers that my regex doesn't catch. Are there other characters than comas or dashes between these duplicates?

indeed, line breaks. I think you need to consider line breaks after a comma, too. When there are a lot of entries, they span several lines.

@BernhardScheffold ah, you are right! I will take a look into this.

@BernhardScheffold it should be fixed in the development version of make4ht now.

looks good now! Thanks a lot!
One thing I am thinking about is that I also use \part. And index entries in the introduction of a part will go to the last section (probably) since the introduction of a part is not really in a chapter or section. I have no idea how to solve this, however.

@BernhardScheffold that would be hard to support, I don't know how we would detect that we are at the start of part. The easiest thing is to start a chapter right after part.

A part starts with \part in the LaTeX source. My book has three parts and for the first two, there is a chapter immediately at the start of the part. I will think about how to make this intro for the third part into a chapter. Maybe that's the best solution.

@BernhardScheffold you can try to add \begingroup\def\thechapter{\thepart}  text of the introduction \endgroup right after the \part command. The grouping is needed for next chapters to work correctly.

I finally tried this out. It kind of works. The intro is for part III and the links to the index entries in this intro have the text III.2.12. The first part (III) seems quite logical, but I can't guess the meaning of 2.12. I probably stick to adding a \chapter{Overview}

I cannot test it now, but it may be easier to just add chapters then
